# What kind of latch would work on this porch door?

Tags: doors, porch

If the hook is unlatched, the hinge springs aren't strong enough to keep the door closed if the wind blows. What can I install to fix this? I see lots of different door latch designs and I'm not sure what would work on this swing open door. Thanks in advance[image: outside]

[image: inside]

Comment: A screen door closer will help a bit with the wind.  A simple lever type gate latch will keep the door closed and can be open from inside or outside.

Comment: @crip659 any hint what type is it

Comment: @Traveler   I do not know the exact name.  They only cost a few bucks and consist of a straight piece of steel that is lifted up by a thumb handle going though the wood.  Gate latch pictures seem to work only one side.

Answer (score 1):

Something from the mid-to-last century when I was just a young lad, what the internet calls a door closer and latch:

[image: Door closer and latch]

[This link](https://www.lowes.com/pd/National-Hardware-3-02-in-Metallic-Hold-Open-Pneumatic-Screen-Door-and-Storm-Door-Closer/1000134215) is the source of the image (Lowe's) but the part is manufactured by National Hardware.

The one I remember and have been unable to locate has a pair of rollers in a C-shape, but the concept is the same. An over-center spring pulls the door closed once it passes the latch.

[image: walmart door closer and latch]

I found this one on the [Walmart site](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Holder-Screen-Door-44-Stain-Chrome/623151587), with both rollers. Among these listings were phrases regarding pneumatic, even though the spring is obvious.